# Make a call to javascript function from actionscript

Tags: javascript, flash, externalinterface

I am trying to make a call to javascript function from actionscript.

As of now, I am using 'ExternalInterface' and could achieve partial success.

I could make a call to function(without any scope resolution) like "scanDNA()", which is visible to all. But am not able to make a call to function(scope specified) like 
"Eukarya.Animalia.Chordata.Vertebrata.Gnathostomata.Tetrapoda.Mammalia.scanDNA()".

Please let me know, how can I achieve this.

Thanks and Regards,

SachinJadhav.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a method in JS to call the function?

```
function scanDNAinSomeScope(){
    Eukarya.Animalia.Chordata.Vertebrata.Gnathostomata.Tetrapoda.Mammalia.scanDNA();
}
```

And call that `scanDNAinSomeScope` using `ExternalInterface`.

UPDATE:

Yes, in that case you need to create a function for every scope. But, you actually only create for functions that you need to call. I believe there wouldn't be many cases you need to call functions from different scope from Flash.

And there is a workaround, using a JS function like:

```
function evil(str){
    eval(str);
}
```

It may be a security hole. But I'm not security expert, so I can't tell what problem it actually has... I know "eval is evil" only :P

Comment: I do not think this is useful...

I want a way out of problem... This is kind of hack...

Comment: Why you think it is a kind of hack? What do you need more than that?

Comment: you would have to create such a function for every scope, not nice indeed

Answer (score 0):

I have never noticed any problems with this. How is your javascript scope structure set up?

Maybe leaving out the "()" in the ExternalInterface call could do the trick..

If I do

```
var animals = {}
animals.mammals = {}
animals.mammals.test = function() {
  return "whee";
}
```

and in flash (CS4)

```
var x:String = ExternalInterface.call('animals.mammals.test');
trace(x);
```

I get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Using the javascript pseudo protocol works well.